# Create an array of buttons in matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

Is there any way to make an array of objects(buttons, static texts, fields, etc. ) whose size is given by the user in matlab gui?

For example the user types 12 in a field and then 12 buttons are created.

P.S.
mathworks.com doesn't let me access its pages. some childish political stuff :&
please answer here.
Thanx!

Comment: Do you want the buttons on the dialog that's being displayed? You need to give a bit more detail. What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't used matlab gui before.
I'm going to get an expression as the input and put a field for each variable in the expression so the user can enter it's value. number of variables in not known before parsing the expression. so I must generate fields after parsing (in the runtime). I mean if the expression has one variable I have to put one field and if it has 5 variables then I have to put 5 fields.

Comment: Just asking - does it have to be a GUI? Can't you just say: "enter value for X", "enter value for blabla", etc- as the need arises, from the command line?

Comment: yes. It should be GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
N = input('How many buttons?   ');

hFig = figure;

hGroup = uibuttongroup('Units','Normalized','Position',[0 0 1 1]);

for i = 1:N
    hText(i) = uicontrol('Style','Text','String',['Variable' num2str(i)],...
        'Parent',hGroup,'Units','normalized','Position',[0 1-i/(N+1) 1/2 1/(N+1)],...
        'BackgroundColor','white');
    hInput(i) = uicontrol('Style','edit',...
        'Parent',hGroup,'Units','normalized','Position',[1/2 1-i/(N+1) 1/2 1/(N+1)],...
        'BackgroundColor','white');
end

hButton = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','Parent',hGroup,'Units','normalized',...
    'String','Go!','Position',[0 0 1 1/(N+1)],'Callback',{});
```

Of course, you can play around with the positions etc. You can put the `uibuttongroup` wherever you want the input fields to appear.

Comment: Yes man that's what I needed!
I don't have enough rep to vote up :(